# Center CSS content: ""; inside <button>

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically and horizontally center `content: "+";`. Vertically I've been able to accomplish this using line-height.
However horizontally, I tried using absolute positioning and then subtract with margin. But didn't work...

This is what I have:

```
html body div.body-container form div#composite-field button#fes-submit {
 position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; right: 5%;
 width: 80px; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 42px;

 border: 0; border-radius: 0; outline: none; -webkit-appearance: none;
 background-color: #2e4856; color: #eab94e;
 z-index: 20;
}

html body div.body-container form div#composite-field button#fes-submit:before {        
 content: "+"; line-height: 100px; float: left;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 42px; letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

[image: The button is the highlighted portion.]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
content:"+";
line-height: 100px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Vertically I am using `line-height:;` and horizontally `display: block;`, `margin: 0 auto;`.

[image]

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` should not work unless you also specify width.

Comment: I have specified width. It just changes from pixels to percents on hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute positioning it might be better to use literal dimension properties such as top,bottom, left, right rather than using a margin. Using a float might also be counter acting the positioning that you want so try removing that. Another option might be to add negative margins to the left or right.

Comment: Thats what I did: `top: 50%;`, `left: 50%;` and then subtract with margin. But it was all distorted. Could not get it to center at all...

Comment: Ignore the float. It's just there cause I was testing something.

Comment: have you tried literal values like px; position absolute with % takes whole viewport into account.

Comment: Can use exact pixels. It needs to be percentage... The button changes width on hover.

Comment: Make sure ur parent element has position set to relative - check out this post as well it might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818792/center-a-pseudo-element

Comment: That won't do either. The button goes over an input field. Needs to be absolute.

Comment: You are always going to have issues when you try position something absolutely with %. My suggestion is to try making it relative and then apply a negative margin which is relative to the input. Otherwise it will cause more uphill than anything else. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Solved it. Take a look at the answer I posted.

Comment: Nice, Glad you figured it out!