# Center an icon there :before

Tags: html, css

I would like to center horizontally and vertically an icon in a link placed there :before.

In spite of my numerous tries, I do not understand why the icon does not want to center.

Here is my html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item-1"><a href="">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my css :

```
ul > li > a {
  font-size:0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

ul > li > a:before {
  font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul > li.item-1 > a:before {
  content:"\2b";
}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xmx4xcfc/

For information, I use bootstrap.

What I do not see?

(for the duplicate with [Center a Pseudo Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818792/center-a-pseudo-element) I would like not to use of position:absolute, and to favor a more "light" solution if it is possible...)

Comment: a fiddle would be nice

Comment: @TylerH i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can vertically align it using `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. The problem seems to be horizontal also

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center;` should be applied to the parent element (`li`) not the anchor tag.

Also, I'd recommend changing the anchor to `display: inline-block;`

```
ul > li > a {
  font-size:0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul > li > a:before {
  font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul > li.item-1 > a:before {
  content:"\2b";
}

ul > li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work (see fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xmx4xcfc/1/)

Comment: @Fluidouix In that fiddle, you have `float: left;` on your `li` element. Either remove that or add `width: 100%;` to `li`

Comment: I tried without `float:left` or with `width: 100%` for the `li` but it does not work :( : https://jsfiddle.net/xmx4xcfc/2/

Comment: @Fluidouix It appears centered for me in the fiddle you posted. What browser are you using? I tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I use Firefox. The "+" is centered for you in the circle ? Strange, I do not see him centered by the whole

Comment: @Fluidouix Yes, it's centered for me.

Comment: @Fluidouix Maybe post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Very strange, the "+" for me isn't centered : [screenshot](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=198883screenshot.png)

Comment: @Fluidouix Yes, that's different from how it looks for me. You can make small changes by modifying `ul > li.item-1 > a:before` to use relative positioning. For example: `position: relative; top: 1px; left: 1px;`

Comment: I always have a gap. I believe that I am going to pass by another technique, background-image or other. Many thanks for your help ;)